# Como serializar/deserializar un nodo de tipo CDATA

Tags: c#, xml

La siguiente clase (de un xml) tiene varios atributos y contiene texto.

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.6.1055.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "xxx")]
public partial class consultaSelect : EntityBase<consultaSelect>
{
   private string scriptField;

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string script
    {
        get
        {
            return this.scriptField;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((this.scriptField != null))
            {
                if ((scriptField.Equals(value) != true))
                {
                    this.scriptField = value;
                    this.OnPropertyChanged("script");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                this.scriptField = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged("script");
            }
        }
    }
    private string valueField;
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTextAttribute()]
    public string Value
    {
        get
        {
            return this.valueField;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((this.valueField != null))
            {
                if ((valueField.Equals(value) != true))
                {
                    this.valueField = value;
                    this.OnPropertyChanged("Value");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                this.valueField = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged("Value");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

El problema esta con value. Yo quiero que sea un CDATA. Sin embargo, al escribir el get de la siguiente manera:

```
get
{
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    return doc.CreateCDataSection(valueField);
}
```

esto en teoria devuelve el valor como CDATA, pero me obliga a decorarlo con un tag `[XmlElement("CDataElement")]` que no es lo que quiero, ya que quiero que forme parte del original. Cuando lo decoro de esa forma, me genera un elemento mas en el XML final:

```
<select script="pepe">
    <CDataElement><![CDATA[SELECT * FROM Users WHERE UserId > 10]]></CDataElement>
</select>
```

y lo que quiero es:

```
<select script="pepe">
    <![CDATA[SELECT * FROM Users WHERE UserId > 10]]>
</select>
```

Entonces el problema es, debo decorarlo de otra forma, o estoy totalmente equivocado y tengo que hacerlo de otra manera?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

espero estás modificaciones te sirvan. Agrega lo siguiente en tu clase

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Schema;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.6.1055.0")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    //[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "xxx")]
    public partial class select : IXmlSerializable//: EntityBase<consultaSelect>
    {
        public select()
        {

        }

        public select(string script, string value)
        {
            Script = script;
            Value = value;
        }


        private string scriptField;

        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
        public string Script
        {
            get
            {
                return this.scriptField;
            }
            set
            {
                if ((this.scriptField != null))
                {
                    if ((scriptField.Equals(value) != true))
                    {
                        this.scriptField = value;
                        //this.OnPropertyChanged("script");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    this.scriptField = value;
                    //this.OnPropertyChanged("script");
                }
            }
        }
        private string valueField;
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTextAttribute()]
        public string Value
        {
            get
            {
                return this.valueField;
            }
            set
            {
                if ((this.valueField != null))
                {
                    if ((valueField.Equals(value) != true))
                    {
                        this.valueField = value;
                        //this.OnPropertyChanged("Value");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    this.valueField = value;
                    //this.OnPropertyChanged("Value");
                }
            }
        }

        XmlSchema IXmlSerializable.GetSchema()
        {
            return null;
        }

        void IXmlSerializable.ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
        {
            if (reader.MoveToContent() == XmlNodeType.Element)
            {
                Script = reader.GetAttribute("script");
                reader.Read();
                Value = reader.Value.ToString(); ;
            }
        }

        void IXmlSerializable.WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
        {
            writer.WriteAttributeString("script", Script);
            writer.WriteCData(Value);
        }

    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var toSerialize = new select() { Script = "pepe", Value = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE UserId > 10" };
            var xmlToDeserialize = "<select script=\"pepe\"><![CDATA[SELECT * FROM Users WHERE UserId > 10]]></select>";

            var result = Serialize<select>(toSerialize);

            var objetDeserialized  = Deserialize<select>(xmlToDeserialize);
            Console.WriteLine(result);

            Console.ReadKey();

        }

        private static string Serialize<T>(T toSerialize)
        {  
            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

            using (StringWriter textWriter = new StringWriter())
            {
                serializer.Serialize(textWriter, toSerialize);
                return textWriter.ToString();
            }
        }

        private static T Deserialize<T>(string toSerialize)
        {
            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

            using (StringReader textReader = new StringReader(toSerialize))
            {
                return (T)serializer.Deserialize(textReader);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: y donde van mis datos guardados en Value? como se relaciona esto con lo que publique? esta el ejemplo de mi clase ahi. voy a ir haciendo pruebas, pero no me queda claro como esto va a arreglarlo.

Comment: edito mi respuesta

Comment: Ok.. vamos bien.. esto esta bastante cerca. Con esto logro que grabe como CDATA la seccion. Sin embargo no logro que lea la seccion. siempre viene vacia. Tambien guarda los atributos. Estaria faltando el detalle para que lea.

Comment: Hola, pensé que solo querías serializar la clase. Me temo que para la deserializacion deberás aplicar  Custom Serialization a través del interfaz IXmlSerializable.

Comment: No hay problema. El titulo dice que quiero hacer las dos cosas. Esto ya es un avance. Gracias igual!

Comment: Modfico mi respuesta con un ejemplo hecho en App Console. He comentado un atributo que tenías establecido y cambiado el nombre de la clase a `select`para la serialización. Tómalo como ejemplo

Comment: Hola @gbianchi, te ha ayudado mi respuesta? Saludos

Comment: todavia no lo probe.. dejame verlo y te digo..

Comment: En el caso de tu ejemplo anda. Mi clase es mucho mas compleja, e implementar a mano toda la serializacion/des es un embrollo. lo termine solucionando de otra forma entre tu ejemplo original y una lectura manual de los campos que no traia. mas alla de aceptar tu respuesta, voy a poner la otra como referencia...

Answer (score 2):

Como refencia, la solucion propuesta por Sergio es totalmente correcta. Sin embargo en mi caso el XML es mucho mas complejo y por eso necesitaba hacerlo con decoradores automaticos. Para evitar eso, hice lo siguiente (aunque no es recomendable):

Agregue lo siguiente en la clase:

```
/// <summary>
/// Serializa, pero no deserializa
/// </summary>
[XmlAnyElement]
public XmlCDataSection CData
{
    get { return new XmlDocument().CreateCDataSection(Value); }
    set { Value = value.Value; }
}
```

y tambien decore el elemento Value como

```
[XmlIgnore]
public string Value
```

Luego de esto, lo unico que hice fue agregar un procedimiento, despues de deserializar el XML, que leyera a mano los elementos CDATA que queria y los guardara en la clase:

```
public static void ObtenerSelectCdata(consulta cons, string rutaarchivo)
{
   XNamespace aw = "xxx";
   XElement NodoConsulta;
   //Abro el archivo
   XDocument documento = new XDocument();
   documento = XDocument.Load(rutaarchivo);
   NodoConsulta = documento.Element(aw + "consulta");
   //Obtengo los nodos Select
   var elementos = NodoConsulta.Elements(aw + "select");
   if (elementos== null)
   {
     //No hay nodos select
     return;
   }
   //Ahora por cada Select que haya en consulta, busco su contenido
   foreach (consultaSelect s in cons.select)
   {
      foreach (XElement xe in elementos)
      {
         if (s.nombreAccion== xe.Attribute("nombreAccion").Value)
         {
             s.Value = xe.Value;
             break;
         }
      }

   }
}
```